# Why am I facing flask-mail issues?

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I am not sure what should I do

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
    app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'sender'
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'sender'
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '*************'
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TSL'] = True
    mail = Mail(app)
    mail.send_message('Mail sent', sender = 'sender', recipients = ['recipients'], body = 'Mail sent successfully')
```

It tells me
`smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server` I've even enabled emails from less secure apps in gmail. Why does it not seem to work?
I've tried looking the error up and haven't found much of a satisfactory answer yet.

Edit: I used SSL instead of TLS for the encryption and it seems to show me a different error. Now it tells me `smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError` I have no idea what to do next. I don't know how to enable DisplayUnlockCaptcha. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha is the link for it. I proceeded with what the link said, it told "Account access enabled
Please try signing in to your Google Account again from your new device or application." and I retried, still fail to sign in.

#### Issue has been fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can try, such as activating `ssl`

```
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
```

> You must not enable both `tls` and `ssl` together

You need to apply a series of settings to your Gmail account, such as disabling `2FA` or `Display Unlock Captcha`, etc.

The steps of the work are outlined in this tutorial.

https://twilio.com/blog/2018/03/send-email-programmatically-with-gmail-python-and-flask.html

Comment: The first issue went away when I used SSL instead, but it gives me a different error now.

Comment: Thanks for the SSL tip, in the edit, I have mentioned my more recent error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local email server for testing like Papercut, it likely does not have AUTH support built in.  So all you have to do is remove the `MAIL_PASSWORD` setting.

this should be your config:

```
# Flask-Mail SMTP server settings
MAIL_SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
MAIL_PORT = 25
MAIL_USERNAME = "noreply@example.com"
```

and this test email sending should work:

```
@app.route("/test/email")
def test_email():
    message = Message(
        subject="Hello",
        sender="abc@example.com",
        recipients=["xyz@example.com"],
        body="This is a test email",
    )
    mail.send(message)
    return "Done"
```

to know more about things like what is `mail` you can follow the [flask mega tutorial email sending chapter](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support)